# Show/Hidden content using Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to hidden/show image file upload section if dropdown list is select option "2", if user select option "1" it should be display image upload option. 
So for example is user select as category "Ponuda" it should display image file upload, if user select potraznja it should hidden image file upload.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

createpostview.php

```
<h2><?= $title;?></h2>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

  </script>


<?php echo form_open_multipart('posts/create/');?>
<?php echo validation_errors();?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mjesto Polaska</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mjestoPolaska" placeholder="Mjesto Polaska">
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mjesto Odredista</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mjestoOdredista" placeholder="Mjesto Odredista">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Datum Polaska</label>
                     <input type="date" id="datepicker" min=<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?> class="form-control" name="datumPolaska" placeholder ="Datum Polaska" >
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Datum Povratka</label>
                     <input type="date" id="datepicker1" min=<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?> class="form-control" name="datumPovratka" placeholder="Datum Povratka">
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Cijena</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cijena" placeholder="Cijena">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
              <label for="select">Broj slobodnih mjesta</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="select" name="brojMjesta">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                  </select>
                </div>


            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kategorije">Kategorija</label>
             <?php 
             echo '<select class="form-control" id="kategorije" name="category_id">';
             foreach($categories as $category) :
                echo '<option value="' . $category['id'] . '">' . $category["name"] . '</option>';
             endforeach;
             echo '</select>';
             ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
             <label>Postavi sliku:</label>
             <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
              <label>Opis:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="opis"></textarea>
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>

            </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
                var element = document.getElementById("category_id");
                element.onchange = function(){
                var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("showMe");
                hiddenDiv.style.display = (this.value=="")?"none":"block";}
            </script>
```

Comment: what you try so far ?

Comment: I deleted the code which I tried  because it's now what I want. Doesnt work

Comment: you should try first because stackoverflow not coding service. no one will help you until they can't show your approch.

Comment: Yes, thank you :) 
I edit my question and add my previous javascript code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try something like blew

get select value on change using javascript/jquery

```
<div class="form-group" id="img_upload">
       <label>Postavi sliku:</label>
       <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
    </div>

    $('#kategorije').on('change', function(){
        var value = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        if (value == 1) {
         $("#img_upload").hide();
        } else {
           $("#img_upload").show();
        }
      });
```

Comment: But now is problem if I not select the picture, the post cannot be uploade and display in my post/view.php
Script now works, but image can not be upload and display

Comment: @yimy You should check php logic for fileupload value, i think you have to pass null value for image in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Base from the html you provided, write a javascript like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#kategorije').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected == 1) {
      // hide the parent element of input
      $('input[name=userfile]').parent().show();
    } else {
      // show the parent element of input
      $('input[name=userfile]').parent().hide();
    }
  });
});
```